# Changing monospace fonts system-wide

Tags: fonts, fontconfig, trisquel

By default, the monospace font for my distribution (Trisquel) is Font A. I would like to change it to font B. Some time ago, I managed to make a partial change to Font C, but I have since forgotten this method and cannot reproduce it.

The trouble is that now I may see all three fonts in monospaced contexts. Using `gnome-tweak-tool` as both root and user, I have changed the "monospace" field to Font B. I have also done this via the command line on gsettings, again as both root and user. However:

- <del>If a web page requests the style `{font-family: monospace;}`, Font C displays.</del> Edit: this was a setting in Firefox, which I have changed.
- In the Inkscape and gedit font menus, there is a font called simply "Monospace", which is font A. My distribution's default UI fonts, which I have changed, also display in these menus under the names "Sans" and "Serif".
- When Thunderbird messages I have received are formatted as plain text, they are displayed in Font A. Unless explicitly changed, messages I write also display in the fonts "Sans" and "Monospace".

How can I fix this situation, such that Font B displays in all contexts described above, and the mysterious "Sans" font is replaced by the UI font I am currently using?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out by searching the system for the name of Font A. There should be a file (more accurately, a link to a file) `/etc/fonts/conf.d/01-trisquel.conf`. You will need to edit this file to include the names of your chosen fonts as highest priority (above the existing `<family>` entries).

Answer (score 20):

Add this to yours `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` file to set Font B as default monospace font

```html
<match target="pattern">
  <test name="family" qual="any">
    <string>monospace</string>
  </test>
  <edit binding="strong" mode="prepend" name="family">
    <string>Font B</string>
  </edit>
</match>
```

Or to `/etc/fonts/local.conf` to set it system-wide.

Comment: The file did not exist, so I created it and added that text to it, surrounded by <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd"><fontconfig> and </fontconfig>. It did not work, even after running sudo fc-cache -f -v.

Comment: To be clear, no need to add <?xml... or anything else to that file. Its exactly as it is shown above. Save. Then you can test if its working with: `fc-match monospace` (be sure "Font B" exists under that name). If you need more than one rule, wrap it around `<fontconfig>` tag.

Comment: This works, but how does one set the size as well? I tried `Font B 14` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

[I found this to be working](https://askubuntu.com/a/893194/266848):

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name 'Noto Mono 11'`

(Probably not all apps, gedit changes instantly)